# Monitor Azure Token Expiration time

Tags: javascript, azure, session, networking, model-view-controller

I am working on a MVC application which uses azure authentication using OAuth2.0
I needed help with monitoring the azure token, by monitoring I mean, I want to setup something that watches the azure token expiration time and when it's about to expire, it throws a warning message to user of session timeout.

I am facing issue that, when the azure token expires all the ajax call fails and all the user data on the page for that specific session is gone, is there any way I could setup a watch for azure token ?

Also another Issue is, when user is active on the page for close to an hour, the token expires silently and the user has to refresh the page in order to continue working on their stuff and this results in loss of all the data they've entered.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When getting token from azure, we usually get token with `expires_in`(indicates the number of seconds for which the access token is valid)/`expires_on`(indicates expiration time) which you could use to monitor token expiration time . And usually token also contains the expiration time . For example, here is an access token issued from azure ad , you could find `iat`(issued at) , `exp`(expiration timeline) info:
[image]

The second issue you could refer to Vittorio Bertocci's article :[Controlling a Web App’s session duration](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2016/07/25/controlling-a-web-apps-session-duration-2/) ,you could inject a  hidden iframe to silently request new tokens to Azure AD. Given that the hidden frame points to the Azure AD domain, as long as there is a valid cookie for Azure AD maintaining a user session, requests for new tokens will not require the user to reenter credentials – and will obtain new tokens silently. In article there is a code sample available in MVC , please refer to that .

Comment: Hey, thanks for that and it really helped. Can you suggest me any way to check cached tokens in browser (chrome)?

Comment: If you store the token in session storage , you could first click F12 to open Chrome's Developer Tools , then find `Resources` , you will find session storage folder/local storage folder ...

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help.. Is there any way I could clear the cached token before loading the iframe, so that it does not load the cached token!!